# Crazy mysql behavior getting different results with almost same query

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I'm trying to make a search function in my website. When i try it out i get very crazy results back.

this query works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM (`products`) 
JOIN `products_field` ON `products`.`id` = `products_field`.`prod_id` 
WHERE menu_id=569 OR menu_id=952 AND (products.title LIKE '%mcgregor%' OR products_field.value LIKE '%mcgregor%') 
GROUP BY `prod_id`
```

But when i change the positions of the menu ids like u see beneath, it gets results where there is nothing with mcgregor in it:

```
SELECT * FROM (`products`) 
JOIN `products_field` ON `products`.`id` = `products_field`.`prod_id` 
WHERE menu_id=952 OR menu_id=569 AND (products.title LIKE '%mcgregor%' OR products_field.value LIKE '%mcgregor%') 
GROUP BY `prod_id`
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `WHERE menu_id IN (952,569)` is what you really want.

Comment: Might also be caused by MySQL's loose group by implementation: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Written this way

```
WHERE menu_id=952 OR menu_id=569 AND ...
```

To mysql is considered a match(true) when menu_id = 952 and what is on the right side of the -OR- is not even evaluated, because you are saying that is this OR the other(the rest of the where declaration) you can wrap this OR like so:

```
WHERE (menu_id=952 OR menu_id=569) AND ...
```

or you can go like so:

```
WHERE menu_id IN (952,569) AND ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding parentheses around the menu section.

```
SELECT * FROM (`products`) 
JOIN `products_field` ON `products`.`id` = `products_field`.`prod_id` 
WHERE (menu_id=952 OR menu_id=569) AND (products.title LIKE '%mcgregor%' OR products_field.value     LIKE '%mcgregor%') 
GROUP BY `prod_id`
```

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is simple: the `where` clause in first query

```
WHERE menu_id=569 OR (menu_id=952 AND (products.title LIKE '%mcgregor%' OR products_field.value LIKE '%mcgregor%'))
```

is different from the one in the second:

```
WHERE menu_id=952 OR (menu_id=569 AND (products.title LIKE '%mcgregor%' OR products_field.value LIKE '%mcgregor%'))
```

You should use parentheses for better clarity, like `(menu_id=569 OR menu_id=952) AND ....`

Regards,